# laravel 5.1 renaming file before uploading on s3

Tags: laravel-5.1

For safety reasons I would like to rename the files submitted to my application before uploading them to S3.  For local storage I can use Storage::move afterwards.  But for S3 I am having trouble.  How do I do it?  Also, instead of using move is it possible to rename them before storing?  Right no my app renames the files without any actions to something like phpK69RGR.jpg  May be I can just configure the random string method?  I also tried using the php rename command before upload but my webservice started erroring out. I know its a very basic question but for some reason I am having trouble with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [outlined in the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#files).

`$request->file('photo')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);`

`$fileName` is an optional parameter that renames the file.

So with that, you could simply place this inside your controller:

```
//Generate random name
$fileName = str_random(30);

$request->file('photo')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
```